# How to use the word 'poise' properly with or without 'is' (to be) (and when with or without)?

Tags: word-usage, passive-voice, active-voice

(1) For example (from https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/poise):

> I **poised** the crowbar in my hand, and waited.

vs.

> The rock **was** poised precariously on the edge of the cliff.

(2) Or another ones:

> he **poised** motionless on his toes

vs.

> The true gentleman **is** subtly poised between an inner tact and an
>   outer defense.

What is the difference in meanings in (2)? Is the last one correct?

Comment: Because the verb "poise" is also transitive, which simply means it can be followed by an object, you can form both passive sentences and active sentences. If the agent is more important you use the passive voice if the subject is more important you use active voice.

Comment: Although **poised the crowbar in my hand** is an oddity. Transitive *poise* does not mean "to hold or grasp in a particular manner" but rather "to position or arrange something so that it remains motionless in that position or arrangement, because it has been so positioned or arranged, not because it is being held in place by something else".  Trying to *balance* a crowbar on your hand, you might say that you poised it *on* your palm. But the word *in* suggests a grasp. Poising and grasping are different things entirely.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I took the example from https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/poise

Comment: @asianirish: I do realize that the example came from Wiktionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **poise** something  means to position it or to arrange it in such a way that it will remain where it was positioned or remain as it was arranged; there is often the sense that it could easily be knocked from that position or out of that arrangement--the stasis is fragile or precarious.

The 'something' which is poised can be one's own person, one's body, or one's mind, attitude, or mental state, if the word is being used figuratively.

> The slapstick comic poised himself on the ladder, holding a flower-pot
>   in his extended arms, waiting for his fellow stooge to walk through
>   the door.
>
> The workers poised the A/C unit precariously on the window sill.
>
> He poised the teaspoon on the tip of his nose.
>
> He poised the broomstick on the tip of his finger and tried to walk across the room.
>
> She poised the mannequin's arm in a languid gesture.

In your second example, the verb is being used figuratively to refer not to an actual physical place or physical arrangement, but a mental attitude or state.

> He stood poised between steely self-control and utter abandon.

There, even though we find the verb **stood** and the preposition **between**, we are not talking about physically standing on two feet with something on either side, but about a state of mind, and two equally powerful attitudes or motives tugging the person's mind in different "directions", so that it is held "motionless", in equipoise.